# Creating a simple command line interface (CLI) using a python server (TCP sock) and few scripts

Tags: command-line, python

I have a Linux box and I want to be able to telnet into it (port 77557) and run few required commands without having to access to the whole Linux box. So, I have a server listening on that port, and echos the entered command on the screen. (for now)

`Telnet 192.168.1.100 77557
 
    Trying 192.168.1.100...

    Connected to 192.168.1.100.

    Escape character is '^]'.`

```
hello<br />

You typed: "hello"<br />
```

**NOW:**

I want to create lot of commands that each take some args and have error codes.
Anyone has done this before?
It would be great if I can have the server upon initialization go through each directory
and execute the **init**.py file and in turn, the **init**.py file of each command call
into a main template lib API (e.g. RegisterMe()) and register themselves with the server as function call backs.
At least this is how I would do it in C/C++.

But I want the best Pythonic way of doing this.

/cmd/
/cmd/myreboot/
/cmd/myreboot/**ini**.py (note underscore don't show for some reason)
/cmd/mylist/
/cmd/mylist/**init**.py
... etc

**IN: /cmd/myreboot/__ini__.py:**
from myMainCommand import RegisterMe
**RegisterMe**(name="reboot",args=Arglist, usage="Use this to reboot the box", desc="blabla")

So, repeating this creates a list of commands and when you enter the command in the telnet session, then the server goes through the list, matches the command and passed the args to that command and the command does  the job and print the success or failure to stdout.

Thx

Comment: Why would you want to write a bad replacement for SSH? If it is going to be a command shell accessible from a unsecured port and allow machine reboots, you are opening a gaping security hole that it's taken decades to secure. You may think that only good people can get at port 77557, until some dope messes with a firewall that you didn't even know existed.

Comment: port 775577 is only accessible on localhost and only a web user with proper credential would have ability to reboot the box. Security risks are understood and no issues there as this is a closed box behind a NAT and the only way to get to that port would be by logging in a web based configuration portal over ssl and click reboot, and if and only if the user has proper credentials, the reboot button appears and request is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build this app using combination of [cmd2](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/python-cmd2/documents/bVa5dmPsKr3AGtab7jnrAJ/download/README.html) and [RPyC](http://rpyc.wikidot.com/) modules.

Comment: cmd2 seems to be just what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Twisted's web server does something kinda-sorta like what you're looking to do. The general approach used is to have a loadable python file define an object of a specific name in the loaded module's global namespace. Upon loading the module, the server checks for this object, makes sure that it derives from the proper type (and hence has the needed interface) then uses it to handle the requested URL. In your case, the same approach would probably work pretty well.

Upon seeing a command name, import the module on the fly (check the built-in import function's documentation for how to do this), look for an instance of "command", and then use it to parse your argument list, do the processing, and return the result code.

There likely wouldn't be much need to pre-process the directory on startup though you certainly could do this if you prefer it to on-the-fly loading.